# Ubuntu Touch - cannot install any apps or updates

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Ubuntu Touch (15.04, r476), cannot install ANY app from Ubuntu Store, but can from Open Store. 
When going to System Settings \ Updates, also none of the app updates can be installed reporting for each the same error:

> DBusError: org.freedsktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied - Destination file
>   path is not writable: "Downloads/"

Removing and re-adding Ubuntu One authentication does not work. Removing ~/ content, and reconfiguring does not help. Permissions are fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a temporary soultiuon until Canonical does something.

PROBLEM: apps tries to download click packages in path `/Downloads/` (which does not exist and it would be in a non writable partition) instead of `/home/phablet/Downloads/`.

SOLUTION: lets make a symbolic link pointing to the right directory in that path:

1) make your filesystem writable until next reboot:

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /`

2) create the symlink:

`sudo ln -s /home/phablet/Downloads/ /Downloads`

3) reboot your phone/tablet because you don't want your system partition to be writable anymore.

Now you must be able to do your updates and install any app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me the other day. No matter what I did, I could not get my updates to download or even install. I also tried removing and then adding my Ubuntu one account and this did not help. The only thing that worked for me was turning of my tablet and then trying again in the morning. The updates then installed fine. Hope you have resolved your issue now.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I even completely reflashed my phone to original (very old) os, which worked, and apps and updates could install. Then I installed the OS base to recent, and again, things stopped to work. I can still install apps via Open Store.